# To change the style of <li> when input is empty

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was making a search field for my website in html but I am not understanding how to change the `display` to `none` using javascript.

```js
function search() {
    var input            =               document.getElementById("myInput");
    var filter           =               input.value.toUpperCase();
    var ul               =               document.getElementById("myUL");
    var li               =               ul.getElementsByTagName("li");


    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

        var a             =            li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        var txtValue      =            a.textContent || a.innerText;

        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        } 

        else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a name">

    <ul id="myUL">
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Agnes</a></li>

        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Billy</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Bob</a></li>

        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Calvin</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Christina</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Cindy</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems working : https://jsbin.com/kafaxedoxu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: That seems like it should work, and it does work in the Stack Snippet....? I wouldn't use `keyup` (I'd use `input`), and there are other changes I'd probably make, but...

Comment: It's not the problem (it could easily be the *next* problem), but: That code is falling prey to what I call [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You need to declare `i`. Not declaring it, in loose mode, makes it a global.

Comment: I want to change the display to none when there is nothing in the textfield

Comment: Put the default state to none, preferably using CSS.

Comment: @KaranGandhi - What part of doing that are you stuck on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here would be a solution : notice the `&& filter` to be sure the input has a value and call the function on page ready to hide it first ;)

```js
function search() {
    var input            =               document.getElementById("myInput");
    var filter           =               input.value.toUpperCase();
    var ul               =               document.getElementById("myUL");
    var li               =               ul.getElementsByTagName("li");


    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

        var a             =            li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        var txtValue      =            a.textContent || a.innerText;

        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 && filter) {
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        } 

        else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
search()
```

```html
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a name">

    <ul id="myUL">
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Agnes</a></li>

        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Billy</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Bob</a></li>

        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Calvin</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Christina</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Cindy</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you've said you want none of the list items to be visible when the text field is empty. Just default to `display: none` and override it when you find  a match.

Doing that with minimal changes:

```js
function search() {
    var input            =               document.getElementById("myInput");
    var filter           =               input.value.toUpperCase();
    var ul               =               document.getElementById("myUL");
    var li               =               ul.getElementsByTagName("li");


    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

        var a             =            li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        var txtValue      =            a.textContent || a.innerText;

        // You could also use .toggle, but sadly IE11 doesn't
        // support the second arg (grrr)
        if (filter && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        
            li[i].classList.add("show");
        } 
        else {
            li[i].classList.remove("show");
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#myUL li {
  display: none;
}
#myUL li.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a name">

    <ul id="myUL">
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Agnes</a></li>

        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Billy</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Bob</a></li>

        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Calvin</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Christina</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Cindy</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As I mentioned in a comment above, if you don't need to support Internet Explorer, you can use [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) instead of `add` and `remove`. You could also use string's `includes` on modern browsers. So:

```
li.classList.toggle("show", filter && txtValue.toUpperCase().includes(filter));
```

---

I'd make more changes, though:

- Declare `i`
- Use modern event handling
- Use the `input` event, not `keyup`
- Don't make `search` a global function
- Use `querySelectorAll`

With those changes:

```js
// Scoping function so we don't create a global
(function() {
    // Hook up the search
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    input.addEventListener("input", search);
    
    function search() {
        var input  = document.getElementById("myInput");
        var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        var items  = document.querySelectorAll("#myUL li");

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var li        = items[i];
            var a         = li.querySelector("a");
            var txtValue  = (a.textContent || a.innerText).toUpperCase();

            if (filter && txtValue.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li.classList.add("show");
            } else {
                li.classList.remove("show");
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

```css
#myUL li {
  display: none;
}
#myUL li.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a name">

    <ul id="myUL">
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Agnes</a></li>

        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Billy</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Bob</a></li>

        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Calvin</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Christina</a></li>
        <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Cindy</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan - Yeah, I kind of forgot an important part of the `if` condition and didn't realize it until i was doing the *second* snippet. :-) Thanks!

Comment: @Kaiido - See the comment in the first snippet, sadly [IE11 doesn't support that argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle). The code seemed like it was written for older browsers, so...

Comment: (I've edited to include something about that after the snippet.)

Comment: Never saw IE11 doesn't support *force*. Fortunately I don't use it myself in production (still with jQuery for max coverage...)

Answer (score 0):

The if has the wrong condition:
Use `filter && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1` which only yields true if `filter` is not falsy (empty string would be) and `filter` is not found in `txtValue`

```js
function search(e) {
  var input = e.target;
  var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  var li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  console.clear()
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

    var a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    var txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;

    if (filter && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('input', search);
```

```css
#myUL .search_li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a name">

  <ul id="myUL">
    <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
    <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Agnes</a></li>

    <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Billy</a></li>
    <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Bob</a></li>

    <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Calvin</a></li>
    <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Christina</a></li>
    <li class="search_li"><a class="search_link" href="#">Cindy</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is working fine, you just have to add the event listener for it like this :
`document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('keyup', search)` after the `search()` function definition, and delete the  `onkeyup="search()"` from the html

Answer (score 0):

Add this condition at the end of your for-loop

```
if(filter==='' || filter===undefined){
    li[i].style.display = "none";
}
```